# Extend tap area of UIBarButton Item to edge of screen

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have set up a custom UIBarButton that I would like to extend out to the edge of the screen, and I can't get it to happen.

I would like to extend the tappable area to the left edge of the screen if possible.

My code looks like this for the button:

```
    btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "Back Arrow"), for: .normal)
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: -100, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)
    btn1.imageEdgeInsets.left = -100
    btn1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    btn1.clipsToBounds = false
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.segueToChooseScreen), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(item1, animated: true)
```

I also tried to implement this, which works at first, but it goes away when I change the screen orientation:

```
    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    // to remove navigation bar extra margin
    for view in (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews)! {
        view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```

My button still looks like this (in landscape mode for instance):

[image: UIBarButtonItem]

Is there a way I can extend it to the edge of the screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: 
You are accessing private api, and code may not work if structure of views or class names are changed. Also note I am making the change in `viewDidAppear`

LAST EDIT: PO wanted view at edge for both portrait/landscape. My actual recommendation would be to use a custom view behaving as a nav bar instead of the code below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50))
    myView.backgroundColor = .red
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myView)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if let navController = navigationController {
        for subview in navController.navigationBar.subviews {
            if String(describing: subview).contains("ContentView") {

                if let guideToUpdate = subview.layoutGuides.first(where: { String(describing: $0).contains("LeadingBar") }),
                    let guideToUpdateOwningView = guideToUpdate.owningView {
                    guideToUpdate.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guideToUpdateOwningView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and thank you for helping! This does the desired effect, but when change the device orientation (to landscape from portrait for instance), it resets back to the way I showed in the screenshot above. I thought putting the code viewDidAppear would have fixed that. it is similar behavior to what I tried above within the viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I started investigating the views hierarchy in landscape and found where the space is added, if you really want to move the button all the way to the edge then maybe should not be using a navigation bar `<UILayoutGuide: 0x600001db4620 - "LeadingBarGuide(0x7fde8240cb40)", layoutFrame = {{44, 0}, {150, 32}}, owningView = <_UINavigationBarContentView: 0x7fde8240db50; frame = (0 0; 812 32); animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6000025b68c0>; bounds.origin=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6000025b6b40>; bounds.size=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6000025b6ae0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000024f85c0>>>`

Comment: Hi, I tried it in the didLayout. Same thing there. I see what you are saying about the extra space. I find that the stock "back" arrow  in the nav bar seems to go to the edge such as in the "News" app in iOS 12. I wonder how to achieve the same effect with a custom barButtonItem then?

Comment: I'm on News app (ios 12.3.1) and the back arrow is not at the edge when in landscape mode

Comment: @TerryB just edited answer with solution for portrait/landscape, approve if you think it solves your problem

Comment: Sorry, I should’ve said the tap area is to the edge of the screen on the news app.

Comment: This works, thank you very much! One thing that is happening is that the button now jumps to the edge a split second after the screen is loaded. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: move the code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead and it won't jump, `viewDidAppear` happens at the very end

Comment: Ok, that works! Thank you so much. I have learned a lot with what you have shown here, cheers!